# What word describes a self -created word/expression with an intuitive meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

> Otherwise, the Court says, there would be no qualified individuals on federal Exchanges, contradicting (for example) the provision requiring every Exchange to take the "'interests of qualified individuals'" into account when selecting health plans. Ante, at 11 (quoting §18031(e)(1)(b)). Pure applesauce.

Like in this above para , it is easily understood that "pure applesauce" denotes nonsense or rubbish and it may or may not have any linguistic roots but the context is still well-understood. What word describes such expressions?

Comment: The OED has "applesauce" used in this way back to 1925.  So are you asking about what to call a word (other than "applesauce") used for the first time in a new sense?

Comment: @GEdgar yes that would be it.

Comment: I'd just like to add a view about dictionaries.  I recognize that English is a "living language" that lacks any authoritative, singular, prescriptive body (the evolution of English between 1600 and 2100 is an obvious consequence).  Dictionaries, therefore, must necessarily reflect usage which may or may not stand the test of time.  Applesauce is an example of a word which may have failed.  Although the OED still retains this usage, it is all but unknown to current speakers.  I question whether purely descriptive lexicons are necessarily the best test for correct current usage.

Comment: I think you are asking the question with the wrong example. *Applesauce* here is just slang. If you were asking for *neologism*, this is not it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you are referring to a **[neologism](https://www.google.com/search?q=neologism)**.

> noun
>  a newly coined word or expression.

(Google)

Comment: Sounds good to me. Or how about "a made-up word"?

Comment: At some point, all words are "made-up words".

Answer (score 0):

Or how about auto-neologism. The word doesn't exist in the dictionary but again, I've just created it. Making "auto-neologism" my auto-neologism.

Comment: Individuals don't decide on wordness.